# Laravel aliases can't be resolved for code coverage generation

Tags: php, jenkins, laravel, laravel-4

I have a fresh setup of Laravel 4 with no tests. I'm trying to set it up for our CI server (running Jenkins) so then I want code coverage. The problem arises when it's trying to generate the clover report, since Laravel is using aliases for classes.

#### Error message

```
Generating code coverage report in Clover XML format ...
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Eloquent' not found in <path>/app/models/User.php on line 6
```

If I change the User model to extend `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` instead of just `Eloquent` (the alias) I do not receive this error. I would prefer to use aliases and if anybody have a solution for this I would be grateful.

#### phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false"
>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Test suite">
            <directory>./app/tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="build/coverage" title="coverage"
            charset="UTF-8" yui="true" highlight="true"
            lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="build/logs/clover.xml"/>
        <log type="junit" target="build/logs/junit.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
    </logging>

    <filter>
        <blacklist>
            <directory suffix=".php">/usr/local/</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">/usr/share/</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">vendor</directory>
        </blacklist>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app/models</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app/controllers</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, this was just an error that occurred if there weren't any tests being executed. I added one test with `$this->assertTrue(true)` and everything works just fine.